# Generate terms that can be pre-calculated (optimisation)

Tags: performance-tuning, factorization

[image]

*(copyable version)*

```
v -> -2 g/j + s/(2 j) + s^2/(4 g j) + t/2
```

We are working with *many* equations similar to the one above. We are using CForm to move these equations into code.

In our code, many of the variables in the equations change infrequently while others change every call.

We'd like to find a way to efficiently extract and pre-calculate terms where possible. In the example above, j, s, and t change very infrequently, while g changes every time. We'd love to find a way to automatically transform the above into something similar to the following:

[image]

I'm aware that in many scenarios a good optimising compiler would make this step unnecessary. For various reasons this is not the case for us, so we need to "pre-optimise".

Thanks!

Comment: I had a look at Experimental`OptimizeExpression but I don't think this will work for us as we need to specify _which_ variables are unchanging.

Comment: Please do not post remarks in the comments. Edit the question instead

Answer (score 5):

For your example, it is possible to use [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect):

```
rewrite[v_ -> expr_, g_] := Flatten @ Reverse @ Reap[
    v -> Collect[expr, g, replace],
    _,
    #2[[1]] -> #1&
]

replace[c_] := Sow[Unique["pre"], c]
```

For example:

```
rewrite[v -> -((2 g)/j)+s/(2 j)+s^2/(4 g j)+t/2, g] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\operatorname{pre35}\to -\frac{2}{j},\operatorname{pre36}\to \frac{s}{2
>    j}+\frac{t}{2},\operatorname{pre37}\to \frac{s^2}{4 j},v\to g
>    \operatorname{pre35}+\frac{\operatorname{pre37}}{g}+\operatorname{pre36}\right\}$

Comment: That is great -- very close to what we need. Do you know why it doesn't work with radicals, eg: rewrite[v -> Sqrt[g + 4 j x y], g]